# Error ORA-06550 and PLS-00103 When Running Oracle Command

Tags: c#, oracle, oraclecommand

When running `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, the following error is displayed:

> System.Exception: 'ORA-06550: Line 1, Column 13:
>   PLS-00103: The symbol "NET_BUSCAR_SOCIO_P1" was found when one of the following symbols was expected:
>
> := . ( @ % ;

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {

            cmd.CommandText = " CALL NET_BUSCAR_SOCIO_P1(vCPF,vExisteSocio,vMatricula,vCodTbSituacao,vNomSocio,vExisteDebito,vExisteRecebimento,vCodTipoSocio,vExisteChequeDev); ";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vCPF", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["vCPF"].Value = cpf;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vExisteSocio", OracleDbType.Int16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vMatricula", OracleDbType.Int16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vCodTbSituacao", OracleDbType.Int16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vNomSocio", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 35).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("vExisteDebito", OracleDbType.NChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vExisteRecebimento", OracleDbType.Int16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("vCodTipoSocio", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 30).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vExisteChequeDev", OracleDbType.Int16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int existesocio = (int)cmd.Parameters["vExisteSocio"].Value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` then the `CommandText` should contain only the name of the stored procedure, i.e:

```
                cmd.CommandText = "NET_BUSCAR_SOCIO_P1";
```

Comment: ORA-06502: PL / SQL: error: character string buffer too small numeric or value
ORA-06512: on line 1

Comment: @PedroTomaz: that's a separate error.  The only character arguments to your stored procedure are output parameters so it seems you're calling the stored procedure okay but not making enough space for the values returned through the output parameters.  You're also not specifying a size for `vExisteDebito`.

Comment: I will change and test. It's because I do not have access to db.

Comment: you solved the puzzle. Thank you.

cmd.Parameters.Add("vExisteDebito", OracleDbType.NChar,6).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;